# Error 1001: no mapping between account names and security ids was done in vs2010

Tags: c#-4.0

The MSI is generated from a VS 2010 setup project for a .NET Windows service targeting .NET Framework 4.
My MSI would install fine and the service would start fine when using VS 2005. 
Only after converting service solution to VS 2010 I started getting the issue. Please guide me.

Answer (score 5):

Just had the same problem;

In the ProjectInstaller.cs designer - right click on "serviceProcessInstaller1" (the default name) and select properties.

Under "account" change it something **other** than the default of "User".

Comment: This worked well for me - I set mine to "LocalSystem", then from the services window set it to my desired user / password.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that if the Setup project was built using Visual Studio 2010, it does not like the format DOMAIN\USERNAME. It only likes the format username@domain.

Answer (score 1):

i got the solution.. the \ is replaced with \\ inside the code and hence the problem exists. so internally replace it with \ through code,so that everything will work fine.